# How to make table columns with the same width in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to make table with two identical screenshots, but the right column is wider then left one. Moreover, it depends on text in the row below, but I don't clearly understand, how it depends exactly.

Two simple examples:

```
![img](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hant0508/tmp/master/1.png) | ![img](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hant0508/tmp/master/1.png)
:---:|:---:
Usage on GNOME 3 | Drag-and-drop on GNOME 3
```

[image]

```
![img](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hant0508/tmp/master/1.png) | ![img](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hant0508/tmp/master/1.png)
:---:|:---:
Usage on GNOME 3 | Drag and drop on GNOME 3
```

[image]

The same text length, the same words... What's wrong with hyphens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Was this in a Wiki, or markdown document? Having trouble reproducing this.

Comment: I think the hyphens make a difference since they make "Drag-and-drop" the widest non-breakable word, thus making the cell's min-content with bigger than if "GNOME" is the widest word.

Answer (score 1):

If the only difference is truly the hyphen, try a different type of hyphen (e.g. an 'actual' hyphen, instead of the minus sign: http://unicode-table.com/en/2010/).

I should say I cannot reproduce this exactly.
The images in my example (left vs. right) are about a pixel or so different, not as much as yours:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was only able to solve it with html. You can add html code directly into the markdown file:

```
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%">First header</th>
      <th width="50%">Second header long</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><img src="https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-194149/images/help/images/view.png"/></td>
      <td width="50%"><img src="https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-194149/images/help/images/view.png"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```